# KeyCloak configuration and Spring permitAll not working

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

I am trying to configure Keycloak with spring boot. But the endpoints that I configure wether its open or with a Role I walys get a 401

```
@Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, 
    jsr250Enabled = true)
    public class KeycloakSecurityConfig extends 
   KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/test/anoymous").permitAll();
        .antMatchers("/test/user").hasAnyRole("user")
        .antMatchers("/test/admin").hasAnyRole("admin")
        .antMatchers("/test/all-user").hasAnyRole("user","admin")
        .anyRequest()
    http.csrf().disable();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Bean
@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
}

@Bean
public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
    return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
}
```

}

When I hit the test endpoint anonymous I get back

{
"timestamp": "2021-07-08T20:39:21.265+0000",
"status": 401,
"error": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Unauthorized",
"path": "/test/anonymous"
}

However even with the keycloak token I get an error which is not authorized... The same as above but with Bearer Token.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test") 
public class KeyController {


@RequestMapping(value="/anonymous", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> AdminEndpoint() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello Anounymous");
}

@RolesAllowed("user")
@RequestMapping(value="/user", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getUser(){
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello User");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/admin", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getAdmin(){
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello Admin");
}
@RequestMapping(value="/all-users", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getAllUsers(){
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello to all");
}
}
```

It runs normally but I checked every spring security configuration on stack as possible as I can but nothing worked. Please help me.

This is the Pom.xml

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.io.keycloak</groupId>
   <artifactId>keycloak</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<properties>
<maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
<spring.version>5.3.4</spring.version>
<keycloak.version>14.0.0</keycloak.version>
<java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>


<dependencies>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
 </dependency>


   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    
    
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
  <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>

   <build>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Comment: could it be because of a typo: anoymous vs ano_n_ymous?

Comment: I switched the endpoints to some easy one like hello and it came back {
    "timestamp": "2021-07-08T20:59:44.177+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/test/uu"
}

Comment: That's not what I meant. Add the missing `n` to `antMatchers("/test/anoymous").permitAll();`. Then see if it works. You have defined an ant matcher for `/test/anoymous` but the request goes to `/test/ano_n_ymous` (the underscores `_` are just there to mark the spelling difference)

Comment: Good observation. But the error persists .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out ...

1 - The class RestController was not being found because it was in another package. So at the main class where the main function is I inputed @ComponentScan for where the RestController was.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.io*") //This was the issue...
public class mainApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Hello
    SpringApplication.run(mainApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

Just an FYI. Even with the @RestController, @Component, @Controller and other annotations where automatically spring would find does not actually work that way. You sometimes need to input @ComponentScan as well.

The result:

[image]